# Is it possible to use combined overflow CSS/JS?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, overflow

I'm looking for a solution for combining different **x** and **y** overflow.

Following code:

```
 div {
 overflow-x: visible;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```

doesn't work. I want a simple method to hide horizontal scrollbar, keeping the vertical overflown content visible. I do not want to change the DIV's height in layout. Any tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a simple method to hide horizontal scrollbar, keeping the vertical overflown content visible.

```
for horizontal -> overflow-x
for vertical   -> overflow-y
```

You could just use

```
div{
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto; // if you don't want scrollbar use visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below.

```
div {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;     
 }
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wK7Yt/)**

The HTML Code:

```
<div>This is a div.</div>
```

**The CSS Code:**

```
div {
 overflow-x: hidden; 
 overflow-y: scroll;
 display:inline-block;
 }
```

Hope this helps.